# Replace on inner property of IEnumerable of objects

Tags: c#, linq, replace, ienumerable

What is the fastest way of doing a replace of an inner property of an collection of objects?

For example:

```
public class MyOuterObject
{
    public IEnumerable<InnerObject> InnerObjects { get; set; }
}

public class InnerObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public class RunClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        IEnumerable<MyOuterObject> objects = GetObjectsFromSomewhere();
        var first = objects.First();
        first.InnerObjects.Where(io => io.Name == "SomeName").ToList().ForEach(o => o.Birthday = DateTime.Now);
        //Replace all InnerObjects on object "first" with those whose Birthday property has been modified

    }
}
```

`objects.GetType()` is

> {System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[MyOuterObject]}

`first.InnerObjects.GetType()` is

> {InnerObject[]}

Comment: `first.InnerObjects.Where(io => io.Name == "SomeName").ToList().ForEach(o => o.Birthday = DateTime.Now);` is not a great idea. If `InnerObjects` was based on a IQueryable, for example, then the code may have literally no effect (it may pull the data out of a database, alter it and then basically throw it away).

Comment: I'd suggest something like: `first.InnerObjects = first.InnerObjects.Select(io => { if (io.Name == "SomeName") { io.Birthday = DateTime.Now } return io});` _Possibly with a `ToList()` at the end, if you are happy to materialise the results._

Comment: @mjwills It's returned from 3rd party code over which I have no control over. :(

Comment: You're right! :) You can add an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: OK, it is backed by an array. Assuming they never change that your original code would work. Or my code would work if you included `ToList()` at the end. Or you could use a `foreach` loop. The latter is probably the simplest.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. I always assumed `ToList()` creates a new instance of an object and thus would not work for this instance.

Comment: `ToList` copies / materialises the `IEnumerable` into a `List`. Because the underlying source is an array, you are copying references to objects - so both the array and the list are pointing to the same objects. So altering one alters the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
 first.InnerObjects = first.InnerObjects.Select(io=>new InnerObject { Name=io.Name, Birthday = DateTime.Now}}).ToList();
```

Alternately:

```
public class InnerObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

   public InnerObject WithBirthday(DateTime date)
           {    return new InnerObject
                 {
                      Name = this.Name,
                      // add other properties here
                      Birthday = date
                };
            }
```

then

```
 first.InnerObjects = first.InnerObjects.Select(io=>io.WithBirthday(DateTime.Now)).ToList();
```

Comment: How does `.ToList()` work in this case? If I do not use `.ToList()` it seems to work async. Why does it happen?

Comment: `first.InnerObjects.Select(io=>io.WithBirthday(DateTime.Now))` just creates an enumerator -- an object that will provide the InnerObjects one at a time.  That object uses (and wraps) the current value of the InnerObjects property, which we are about to replace.  The `ToList()` pulls all the elements out of it, transforms them and put them in a list before assigning it to InnerObjects